# How to ignore terms in replace if they do not exist in the pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, replace

I have the following code to replace one term with another, this only works if the value exists in the pandas dataframe, I assume I need to wrap `gdf[montype] = gdf[montype].replace(dict(montype), regex=True)` in an `if statement`? How would I do this, or is there a better way?

```
    montype = [
        ['HIS_COP_', ''],
        ['_Ply', ''],
        ['_Pt',''],
        ['BURIAL','burial'],
        ['CUT', 'CUT'],
        ['MODERN', 'MODERN'],
        ['NATURAL', 'NATURAL'],
        ['STRUCTURE', 'STRUCTURE'],
        ['SURFACE', 'SURFACE'],
        ['TREETHROW', 'natural feature'],
        ['FURROW', 'FURROW'],
        ['FIELD_DRAIN', 'FIELD_DRAIN'],
        ['DEPOSIT_FILL', 'DEPOSIT_FILL'],
        ['POSTHOLE', ''],
        ['TIMBER', ''],
        ['', '']
    ]

    gdf[montype] = gdf[montype].replace(dict(montype), regex=True)
```

When the term does not exist I get the error `raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")`

Edit:

```
    mtype = {
                'HIS_COP_': '',
                '_Ply': '',
                '_Pt': '',
                'BURIAL': 'burial',
                'CUT': 'CUT',
                'MODERN': 'MODERN',
                'NATURAL': 'NATURAL',
                'STRUCTURE': 'STRUCTURE',
                'SURFACE': 'SURFACE',
                'TREETHROW': 'natural feature',
                'FURROW': 'FURROW',
                'FIELD_DRAIN': 'FIELD_DRAIN',
                'DEPOSIT_FILL': 'DEPOSIT_FILL',
                'POSTHOLE': '',
                'TIMBER': ''
               }  # dict(montype)

    gdf['montype'] = gdf['montype'].map(mtype).fillna(gdf['montype'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# Convert you list to dict

Montype={'His_cop':'','Modern':'Modern', etc...} # dict(montype)

gdf[montype]=gdf[montype].map(Montype).fillna('whatever value you want')
```

Comment: That converts all values to `nan` code edit added with Montype changed to mtype

Comment: with `.fillna()` added, the nans change as expected, but they are still all turned to nan as previous comment.

Comment: Thats mean gdf['montype'] column does  not contain any of the dictionary keys. Plesse post a sample of your dataframe